# how to get different classed elements in the same node list?

Tags: javascript, css, nodelist

i need to get two different elements with different classes in the same node list. 
like if i could do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".a, .b");
```

so it would have to be like getting the elements with .a class but if there is a .b class element between them it would get put in the list too, not at the end, but where it would be in the list if it had the same class too.
like if i had this:

```
<div class="a">
<div class="b">
<div class="a">
```

the first .a would be the first in the list, the first .b would be second in the list, the third .a would be third.

Comment: How about a `div` around the `HTML` you posted, and a selector like `document.querySelectorAll("div div");`...

Comment: i think it would screw things up if i added anything

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but it seems like what you have will work:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".a, .b");

console.log(divs);
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    console.log(divs[i]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w5wthknL/1/

Comment: oh... i will have to try it again then